# ImportError: cannot import name 'Hyperparameters' from 'kerastuner.engine.hyperparameters'

Tags: python, keras, hyperparameters

While importing **from kerastuner.engine.hyperparameters import Hyperparameters** I am getting below error in the Jupyter Notebook. However while running **import kerastuner as kt** I am not getting any error. I am using tensorflow 2.2.

Comment: Those are completely different imports, so there shouldn't be a surprise that one fails while the other one succeeds. Are you sure you spelled everything right in the failing import? I don't know anything about the software your working with, but googling your error indicates that you are not, in fact, spelling everything right…

Comment: Did you try checking the documentation?

Comment: Thanks @gspr, as you mentioned, it was a spelling mistake. It should be HyperParameter.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this :

from kerastuner.engine.hyperparameters import HyperParameters